# How to use wxpython's DataViewCtrl Drag and Drop

Tags: python, python-2.7, drag-and-drop, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to use drag&drop in combination with `wx.dataview.DataViewCtrl`, so I started with trying to reorder rows using Drag&Drop. I was unable to find any examples how to do this correctly in wxpython, but anyhow, I managed to get it partially working (see below).

Unfortunately, `event.GetDataObject()` always returns `None` in my `on_drop` function. Any pointers how to get the DataObject I assigned in `on_begin_drag`? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**Setup:**

- ArchLinux (64-Bit)
- python2 2.7.9-1
- wxpython 3.0.2.0-1
- gtk3 3.14.8-1
- gnome-shell 3.14.3-2

**Example Code:**

```
import wx
import wx.dataview

DF_PLAYLIST_SONG = wx.CustomDataFormat("playlist_song")

class MyDataViewCtrl(wx.dataview.DataViewCtrl)
  def __init__(self, *args. **kwargs)
    [...]
    self.Bind(wx.dataview.EVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_BEGIN_DRAG, self.on_begin_drag)
    self.Bind(wx.dataview.EVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_DROP, self.on_drop)

    self.EnableDragSource(DF_PLAYLIST_SONG)
    self.EnableDropTarget(DF_PLAYLIST_SONG)

  [...]

  def on_begin_drag(self, event):
    text = self._model.GetValue(event.GetItem(), 0)
    data = wx.CustomDataObject(DF_PLAYLIST_SONG)
    # Need to encode, because SetData dislikes unicode
    data.SetData(text.encode('utf-8'))
    event.SetDataObject(data)
    #data.this.disown() # Makes no difference if uncommented or not

  def on_drop(self, event):
    print(event.GetDataFormat()) # Returns DF_PLAYLIST_SONG
    if event.GetDataFormat() == DF_PLAYLIST_SONG:
      # This would be logical choice:
      print(event.GetDataSize()) # Returns the size of the data, e.g 92
      print(event.GetDataObject()) # Returns None (strange!)
      # Some other stuff I tried
      print(event.GetClientObject()) # Returns MyDataViewCtrl instance
      print(event.GetEventObject()) # Returns None
      print(event.GetValue()) # Returns <Swig Object of type 'wxVariant *' at 0x7fffa340a0d0>
      print(self._model.GetValue(event.GetItem(), 0)) # Returns column 0 of the row this was dropped on
      print(event.GetItem()) # Returns the wx.dataview.DataViewItem this was dropped on
      print(event.GetDataBuffer()) # Returns <Swig Object of type 'void *' at 0x1a59b30>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get back the data object in `wxEVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_DROP` hander, it's only used for dragging data away from the control. When dropping, you get the raw data and its format, i.e. you should use `GetDataSize()` and `GetDataBuffer()` to access it.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a hint how to do that (i.e. get data from the buffer)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it in Python neither. Let's hope Robin can address [your ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/16881).

Answer (score 0):

See [this example on a wxWidgets/wxPython ticket 15100](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/attachment/ticket/15100/tree.py). I used it to make drag/drop for a `wx.DataViewCtrl` and a tree-ish data structure happen (to get an object back). Works at least on 2.9.5/msw. `HitTest` has been implemented in 3.0.2 (if you want to know which item got hit).

May not be the proper answer for your problem but at least it does work (see the crazy pickling of the object item).